Inconsistent interpolation of DFT band structure (BoltzTraP2)
I want to compute transport properties for pristine and doped material using BoltzTraP2 .The consistent interpolation of DFT band structure of pristine case (P63/mmc, 4 atoms) is achieved with dense k-mesh and gradient of energy method. However, the interpolation for doped case (P-3m1 supercell of 32 atoms) is not consistent with its DFT one (see Figure below) even though a gradient of energy method, a dense Monkhorst-Pack k-mesh of 15x15x9 in nSCF (DOS) step and a dense sampler (-m: 100 ) is used. My understanding is that the interpolation should match exactly (consistent) with its DFT one before moving further to the integrate step. I need help to resolve this issue.
Command used to plot interpolated bands:
btp2 plotbands -k 100 interpolation.bt2 ["[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.3333333333, 0.3333333333, 0.0000000000], [0.5, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.0, 0.5], [0.33, 0.33, 0.5], [0.0, 0.0, 0.5]"]

KPOINTS used for computing DFT band structure:
0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000    Γ
0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000    K

0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.0000000000    K
0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000    M

0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000    M
0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000    Γ

0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000    Γ
0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000    A

0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000    A
0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000    L

0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000    L
0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.5000000000    H

0.3333333333     0.3333333333     0.5000000000    H
0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000    A 



Are these definitely along the same k-point path? Please could you adjust the scales to be consistent, to help us to compare them?

@PhilHasnip I too noticed that interpolated band structure appears to have been plotted along different path, but I have used the same (line mode) k-pt coordinates used in DFT band structure calculation (OP mentions this). I do not get how (and where) to adjust the scale, please suggest. Moreover, I did not adjust scales in pristine case but used DFT k-pt coordinates as it is to plot interpolation, yet they looked consistent. Does doped case need it as it is a supercell case?
